# How to set third image for NSButton mixed state

Tags: xcode

I'm using interface builder in Xcode

I want to add a checkbox with 3 states (Allows mixed state set to true in interface builder)

[image: Allows Mixed State]

With a custom image for each of the three states, however I can only see a way to set two images

[image: Image alternate image]

Image appears to be used for `off` and Alternate appears to be used for `on` and `mixed`

Is there a way to set a different image for `mixed`?

Comment: Take a look at Apple's [HIG for checkboxes](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/buttons/checkboxes/) and see if that helps.

Comment: @fsb Thanks Id taken a look through there already. They work fine when you don't put custom images, it has a placeholder image for the three states. It's just I can't figure out how to replace the mixed state image if I want to style the checkbox

Comment: I didn't know you could use an alternate image for mixed state.  I thought 'alternate' was only for 'off'.  I'll see if I can find anything but my initial searches weren't successful.